# Grails: How do I use a request scoped service in a tag library?

Tags: grails, taglib

I'm relatively new to the Grails community, but I love already what the engine has to offer. Currently, I'm implementing a custom tag library in order to easily facilitate a standard design on our pages. However, I need a way of calling helper functions for utility purposes (e.g. filtering data) and to stash request level meta data about my tags (e.g. counters, parent/child relationships).

I have attempted two solutions:

First: I've created a service, set its scope to "request"

```
package myapp

class CustomTagService {
    static scope = 'request'
    def data = []

    def add(localData) {
        data.add(localData)
    }
}
```

However, when I try to inject it in my tag library

```
package myapp

class MyTagLib {
    def customTagService

    def myTag = { attrs, body ->
        customTagService.add(attrs)
    }

}
```

The engine yells at me for referencing a request scope (after a long painful stacktrace): "**Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton**"

Second: I understand the pageScope is available to me inside of a tag closure, and I've exploited it before. However, for the structure I am wanting, encapsulation would be much preferred.

Please let me know if I am going down the wrong path on this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: The `CustomTagService` is just to hold data? If so, why not create a groovy class and set this in the pageScope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use scoped beans in singleton beans since the singleton beans (including taglibs) are created at startup when there's no request active. Instead use a scoped proxy (a bit complicated) or just get the bean from the `ApplicationContext` for each use at runtime when there is an active request:

```
package myapp

class MyTagLib {

   def grailsApplication

   def myTag = { attrs, body ->
      customTagService.add(attrs)
   }

   private getCustomTagService() {
       grailsApplication.mainContext.customTagService
   }
}
```